# WILL or Present Continuous

Tags: tense, present-continuous

In Solutions Advanced (2nd edition), there is a tricky sentence in the Grammar Builder and Reference part of the chapter 1B:

> **My sister often gets annoyed with her husband, he ___ .**

Option A: *is always winding* the children up.

Option B: *will* wind the children up.

Both seem logical to me for A expresses and annoying repeated behaviour and B is about a habitual action (in accordance with the adverb *often* in the main clause). Either of them can be correct, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have look at both of your sentences, I cannot see to it that there is much difference in meaning between them. Nonetheless, let's point out *some grammatical rules*:

> **1)** My sister often gets annoyed with her husband since ***he is always/constantly
>   winding the children up.***
>
> **2)** My sister often gets annoyed with her husband since ***he will [always - needless, but it could be inserted] (habit) / would (behavior)*** wind
>   the children up.

**1)** When we use the present continuous tense with the adverbs such as : ***always, forever, constantly, etc., we are trying to emphasize that something is done so often that it is characteristic/behavior of a person, or group. Besides, we can use the present continuous to describe something we regularly do at a certain time***, *whereas in*

**2)** *we are talking about characteristic behavior or habits; things that are/were always true.*

However, there is another way the sentence could be read:

***3) My sister often gets annoyed with her husband because of his winding the children up.***

Still, sentences *1), 2), and 3)* could sound like more emphatic and detailed variants of:

*My sister often gets annoyed with her husband since **he winds the children up.***

So, yes. **Both of the aforementioned are correct!**